# Create new numeric variable based on condition

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new variable that consists of the patients weight in kg at the time of visit 1, but I am having trouble with the logic.  I have tried the following code but have have no luck

```
WL_A <- function(visitnum, Weight_KG) {
  if (visitnum == 1)
    return(Weight_KG)
}
```

**data**

```
structure(list(Sid = structure(1:5, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E"), class = "factor"), Weight_KG = c(100L, 500L, 70L, 
90L, 82L), visitnum = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 12L), BMI = c(13L, 25L, 
20L, 18L, 7L)), .Names = c("Sid", "Weight_KG", "visitnum", "BMI"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: And what's your question/problem?

Comment: I am having trouble creating a new variable called WL_A that only includes the weight of patients (numeric) at visit 1.  The function I wrote only returns T/F which isn't very helpful

Comment: Is there data behind this? What does it look like? What is its structure? How is your function to know about a patient (as you have it set up, it takes in a visit num and a weight, and if the visit is 1, it outputs the same weight it was input)? Maybe have a look at [How to make a reproducible example in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061) for a nice walkthrough of how to ask a good *answerable* question.

Comment: Cannot answer without reproducible example, but you likely want `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(patientID) %>% mutate(first.weight = Weight_KG[visitnum == 1])`

Comment: Ah sorry im so new this is how the data frame is structured

 Sid     Weight_KG      visitnum     BMI 
1 A               100                 1             13
2 B                500                2             25
3 C                70                 1             20
4 D                90                 1            18
5 E                 82                 12            7

Comment: Does this give you the desired result: `df$WL_A <- ifelse(df$visitnum == 1, df$Weight_KG, "")` ? The class of `df$WL_A` is character though.

Comment: Thanks for the `dput`, that is very helpful. Could you also show your desired result? A new column added to your data? Or a separate data frame with just the first weights? If it's a new column, try Renu's code, replacing `patientID` with `Sid`.

Comment: yes it did thank if you!

Comment: @markus use `NA` instead of `""` to keep it integer.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks. You're right of course. Just wasn't sure about the expected output.